# annotating by one-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm, one-to-many, django-annotate

Let's say I have these two models:

```
class Test1:
   ...........
class Test2:
    test1 = models.ForeignKey(Test1, related_name = 'tests')
    isCompleted = models.BooleanField()
```

and I want to make this query:

```
queryset = Test1.objects.annotate(is_completed = ExpressionWrapper(Q(tests__isCompleted = True ),output_field = BooleanField()))
```

of course this is giving me a None when I do this:

```
queryset[0].tests.first().is_completed
```

What I am trying to do is I want to check if only one of the related `tests`(the related objects to Test1) has a field `isCompleted` with the value `True`.
So my question is what's is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instance of `Test1` (saved as `test1`, for example) and you just want to know if that instance has any related `Test2` with `isCompleted` you could do:

```py
Test2.objects.filter(isCompleted=True, test1=test1.id).exists()
```

This would return a boolean of whether or not exists a `Test2` with `isCompleted = True` related to your `Test1`.

If what you want is to get all `Test1` that has at least one related `Test2` with `isCompleted = True`, you could do:

```py
Test1.objects.filter(tests__isCompleted=True).distinct()
```

Comment: sure but i want to annotate the boolean value to test 1 objects because i used fetch_related method to fetch the test2  related objects